# Optimizing a query - using a field or using another table

Tags: sql, hibernate, database-design, jpa

I have a query which takes a long time and I want to optimize it. I'm looking for the most efficient way to do it.

I'm working on Hibernate/JPA with Postgresql DB but any solution should be a generic JPA one.

**Terminology**

- User: A user in the system.
- Friend: A friend of the user. A user will have N friends.
- Session: A session of using the system. Can be open or closed.
- Context: A context of the session. A user may have one open session per context in any given time, and may have many past closed sessions per context.

**The query**

I need to implement a query that, given a user name, gives me the following:

- Fetch all the friends of that user
- For each friend:

  - If the friend has any open sessions, fetch all the open sessions (for all the contexts)
  - Otherwise, get the friend's latest session out of all the contexts.

Note that the friendships are stored in a different DB so I cannot incorporate that into one big query in any case.

**Example**

User A has three friends: B,C,D. There are two contexts, 1 and 2. The friends have the following data:

(The formatting below is Session ID - User,Context)

- 1 - B,1: Open session
- 2 - B,2: Closed session that started on Feb-27
- 3 - B,2: Closed session that started on Feb-26
- 4 - C,1: Closed session that started on Feb-27
- 5 - C,1: Closed session that started on Feb-26
- 6 - C,2: Closed session that started on Feb-26
- 7 - C,2: Closed session that started on Feb-25
- 8 - D,1: Open session
- 9 - D,2: Open session

The query should get me:
B: Session 1 (All open sessions)
C: Session 4 (Latest closed session)
D: Sessions 8,9 (All open sessions)

**Current state**

My query works in three steps:

1. Get all the friends of the user
2. For each friend:

   1. Get all the open sessions for the friend
   2. If there is any open session, return all the open sessions
   3. Get the latest session for the friend, return that session

Obviously this is a lot of queries. **For starters, I'm going to take step 2 above and convert it into a single query**. My concerns are related to that second query. The question is - how to make it more optimized. The problem can be therefore rephrased:

"Given a set of N friend IDs, get all the open sessions or the latest session for all these friends."

**Suggested solutions**

There are basically two solutions we came up with and we're contemplating what would be better.

The table solution says to keep a new table that will correlate between user, context, and latest session. The implications of this solution are:

- Create a new entity & table for "latest sessions"
- The table will have these columns:

  - User
  - Context
  - Latest session ID
- The table will be updated by the session entity on post persist, so that any newly persisted session will automatically update this table.
- The new query will fetch all the records for all the friends of the user from this table and work on them to create the final result.

The column solution says to keep a "latest" flag column on the sessions table. The implications of this solution are:

- Create a new field for the latest (a boolean)
- The column will be set by the post persist of the session entity, so that the former "latest" session will no longer be the latest, and the new session will become the latest one.
- The new query will fetch all the latest records (by incorporating the new column into the condition of the statement) for all the friends of the user from the original sessions table and work on them to create the final result.

There are pros and cons to each of these, and we don't seem to have a winner yet. Obviously there may be other, better solutions we have not considered. What I'd like to see is which of the above is better and why, or a new better approach of your own.

Comment: How about using a view with a function?
Also caching might be a big help, if possible.

Comment: As far as I understand it, a view would just run the complicated query one way or another, and I'm trying to avoid this situation by incurring some more management during the DB updates, thus improving the performance of the query.

Comment: Why different DB for friendships? Is it really different DB or different schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your two solutions should be marginal. Table solution might be cleaner depending on activity.

However, do note that 'you are doing it wrong' (according to the theory).

The RDBMS application design principle clearly states that you should not try to specify how your queries should be executed, but what data you want. The database will find optimal path to your solution (the RDBMS sits closest to the data and depending on your architecture might save network round trips, storage round trips and so on; scalability can be seriously crippled here and you might not be aware of it if you don't do decent stress testing; furthermore RDBMS knows about indexes and internal statistics that determine if scans or seeks will be more effective and it knows how to optimally execute joins).

In practice, try to raise the question why different database for friendships? (is it really different db or different schema on the same db?).

Furthermore, if you really want to go the way you do it (disabling the RDBMS to look for optimal execution plan), then the most important factors are:

- indexes (will affect the performance in orders of magnitude)
- usage patterns (indexes will improve performance of SELECTs, but too many indexes will slow down updates)
- application/client layer caching (can affect performance and scalability in orders of magnitude)

EDIT:
So, considering "Given a set of N friend IDs, get all the open sessions or the latest session for all these friends." here is a query that should be tested before introducing new structures

Sessions (SessionID, User, Context, Start, End)

```
SELECT *
FROM Sessions s
WHERE s.End IS NULL 
      AND s.User IN (:friendsList)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Sessions s
WHERE s.User NOT IN (SELECT User 
                     FROM Sessions s2
                     WHERE s2.User IN (:friendsList)
                           AND s2.End IS NULL)
      AND s.User IN (:friendsList)          
      AND s.End IN (SELECT MAX(End) 
                    FROM Sessions s2 
                    WHERE s2.User = s.User)
```

There are more ways to write the above to try to help the optimizer, in particular if your DB supports CTE the above can be rewritten more efficiently.

Notes:
`:friendsList` - list of Users that are friends.
Also, I am assuming open sessions have NULL as value of the `End` for open sessions. You might already be choosing some other approach (maybe you have a field denoting it; or there are two tables, one for open sessions, one for closed)

The above query will benefit from certain indexes (principle is to first try to optimize with indexes, then with restructuring; first index I would try is composite index on `User, End`) and on relatively small number of friends (assumed from the fact that it passed around as a string), this should perform decently already.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see I'm not trying to optimize a given query - I know that the query is complicated so I'm trying to add more information to the DB in order to simplify it. If you wish, I'm adding data to the database in order to simplify the eventual query logic. Is that wrong according to the theory?

Comment: @Eldad Mor, yes, according to good design principles it is wrong. Reasons a) you had already split what should have been one query into three b) now to improve the poor performance of the three queries you are starting to build caching structures. Now this indeed in practice is sometimes the only way to significantly improve performance; however as you didn't start with a single query then this is a case of premature optimization and you might be developing a solution for a non-existent problem (actually existent, but self-made).

Comment: Ok, I agree with your point of view, though it's 2 queries and not three. I basically think that creating the second query given the existing DB schema is going to be both complex in terms of SQL and lengthy in terms of performance. I agree about avoiding premature optimization but this is going to be, by far, the most complicated query - and I believe that by adding some data to the DB I will simplify it dramatically.

Comment: @Eldad Mor, I have updated the answer with the way your 2nd query would look without additional structures. Indeed the SQL is more complicated then what you would have with extra table or field. However it is not very complex. You should also compare the overall complexities - your solution will require extra code (and it will be somewhere else - on the application level/unless you use triggers; this code might need maintenance or might get bypassed by a DBA, etc..). Alternatively, to simplify the query, you might create a VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

why not cache objects? You do not need to hit the DB.

Comment: I am using caching, however this query is not a frequent one. Users will use it once in a while but not often enough to allow caching to really improve the performance.

Comment: Though this query is not a frequent one since you say the objects are already in cache then why not use it? If the following objects are in cache - User,Friends(User), Session then its simple object look up. However with the DB options you have outlined

Comment: 1. Creating a new table will add a lag on Session save & you also need to eliminate it when session expires. Its a bit of an overhead.Yes, select would be faster. Its also introduces bit of data redundancy. If the Session table has huge number of records then this approach may work better.

2. Not much additional overhead as its another column in update. However if Sessions table has voluminous data then queries are going to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Your main bottle neck appears to be the fact that the information you need is distributed over two databases.  Thus, you acquire a list of friends and itterate through them.

I would suggest that you attempt to remove the itteration, reducing it to a single query instead.

The way I would achieve this is build up a comma delimited string of user ids, and pass that string to the second database.  The sql in the second database could then (using a function, for example) translate the string intol a single field table of ids, and join on that.

It feel very inellegant to me, yet it's something I do all the time.

The only practical alternative that I have used is to build up a single query that inserts the IDs in to a table, then join on that.   Either a temporary table, or a permanent table with a SessionID field allowing multiple sessions to use it concurrently.

Whatever approach you use, have a single query for step 2, using a set based approach rather than itteration, should yield significant benefits.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear :-) I don't want to iterate over the friends and query for each. I do intend to run a single query on the complete list of the friends. I cannot merge the two DBs, that's a given, but I can convert the whole process into two queries - one for fetching friends and the other for fetching the sessions. It's the second query I'm concerned about here.